# Strong convergence, functional analysis problem

Tags: functional-analysis

We know, that
$$ u_n \to u \mbox{ in } L_4(0,1) \,\mbox{ and }\, f_n \to f \mbox{ in } L_4(0,1).  $$

Is always true that

$$ u_nf_n \to uf \mbox{ in } L_2(0,1) \ ? $$

Thank for help.

Comment: $u_n f_n - u f = (u_n - u) f_n + u (f_n - f)$ and apply Cauchy Schwarz

Comment: Note that (for this domain) $\|x\|_2 \le \|x\|_4$.

Comment: @copper.hat: Where do you need this inequality?

Comment: So that you know $u,u_n,f,f_n$ are in $L_2$ and you can apply Cauchy Schwartz Beiber Bunyakovsky inequality.

Comment: @BeatriceK: Why is this question tagged with "weak convergence"? Does "$\to$" indicates weak convergence in your question?

Comment: @copper.hat: I still do not get it. You did not need to evaluate something like $(v,w)_{L^2(\Omega)}$ for any $v,w \in \{u, u_n, f, f_n\}$. So Cauchy-Schwarz will not help. (And who is "Beiber" btw.?)

Comment: @gerw: Sloppy thinking on my part. The Beiber is just a joke. Every time I see the Cauchy Schwartz Bunyakovsky inequality I feel the need to add at least one more name :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is strong convergence, not weak.

If $x,y \in L_4(0,1)$ then $|x|^2,|y|^2 \in L_2(0,1)$ and
Hölder/Cauchy Schwarz gives 
$\int |x|^2 |y|^2 \le \|x\|_4^2\, \|y\|_4^2$. That is,
$\|xy\|_2 \le {\|x\|_4 \|y\|_4}$.

We have $u_nf_n - uf = (u_n -u)f_n + u (f_n - f)$ and so
\begin{eqnarray}
\|u_nf_n - uf \|_2 &\le& \|(u_n -u)f_n\|_2 + \|u (f_n-f)\|_2 \\
&\le& {\|u_n-u\|_4 \|f_n\|_4} +{\|u\|_4 \|f-f_n\|_4}
\end{eqnarray}
Hence $u_nf_n \to uf$ in $L_2(0,1)$.